# Looking for solution on calculating distance between two curves

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I need to calculate minimum and maximum distance between two curves (normal)
i.e. points from one curve have a perpendicular on another.
What i have done so far:

```
from sympy import *
from pandas import DataFrame
init_printing(use_unicode=False, wrap_line=False)
x = Symbol('x')

F=x+1 #first curve
G=x**2 #second curve
#on the interval [1:5]

My_list =np.transpose( [np.arange(1, 5, 1)] )
df = DataFrame(My_list, columns=['x']) # x array to data frame
df['yF'] = df['x']+1  #adding first function
df['yG'] = df['x']** 2 #adding second function
df['r']= abs(df['yF']-df['yG']) #calculating distance
df.describe()  #to look min-max
```

The problem is: distances are not really a perpendicular to a curve... solution does not look optimal.

Comment: First you need to learn what math to use for this, then you can program it.

Answer (score 0):

You are NOT finding the perpendicular distance. You are finding the minimum of the y-values with fixed x values. Your steps need to look like this:

1. find all perpendicular lines to one of the curves.
2. find the corresponding intersection point on the other curve.
3. calculate the distance.

Note that this method is not commutative, the perpendicular distance from f to g may not be the same as the perpendicular distance from g to f. This is because you are not guaranteed that if a line is perpendicular to curve f that it must also be perpendicular to curve g.

Some math:

1. the derivative of F is 1
2. the derivative of G is 2*X
3. the perpendicular line of Y=X+1 at a point x is Y=-X+(2*x+1).
4. the perpendicular line of Y=X**2 at a point x is Y=-1/(2*x)*X+(x**2+0.5)
5. the intersection points could have more than one solution

I will show in numpy.

```
import numpy as np

#Functions, d is the derivative
F  = lambda x : x+1  
dF = lambda x : np.ones(x.shape)
G  = lambda x : x**2
dG = lambda x : 2*x

#Domain
X  = np.arange(1,5,1)

#We calculate the distance from G to F
P_m = -1/dG(X)                                  #Perpendicular slopes
P_b = X**2+0.5                                  #The y-intercept
C   = (2*X**3-X)/(2*X+1)                        #The x-coor of the intersection
D   = np.sqrt((X-C)**2+((P_m*X+P_b)-F(C))**2)   #Distance
print(D.min())

#Now the other way (this way has two intersection points). 
P_m = -1/dF(X)                                  #The perpendicular slopes 
P_b = 2*X+1                                     #The y-intercepts 
C1  = 0.5*(-P_m+np.sqrt(P_m**2+4*P_b))          #First solution
C2  = 0.5*(-P_m-np.sqrt(P_m**2+4*P_b))          #Second solution 
D1  = np.sqrt((X-C1)**2+((P_m*X+P_b)-G(C1))**2) #Euclidian distance to first solution
D2  = np.sqrt((X-C2)**2+((P_m*X+P_b)-G(C2))**2) #Euclidian distance to second solution
D   = np.concatenate([D1,D2])                   #Distance
print(D.min())                                  #Minimum distance
```

Comment: can you please explain more detailed: 'the perpendicular line of Y=X+1 at a point x is Y=-X+(2*x+1).' 
- how you calculated this? and this 'P_m = -1/dG(X) '  I think if we have F first function and array of x,
 we can calculate starting points of perpendicular. later we have perpendicular line function and  the second G function. 
We can solve this system of equations  and have intersection between line and G function. at the end knowing two points we can calculate distance

Comment: This is really a math question not a stackoverflow question. In general, if two lines intersect at right angles, L1 and L2, and the slope of L1 is m, then the slope of L2 must be -1/m. This is a known fact about lines and the basis for finding the perpendiculars to a curve. In general, for any curve, Y = F(X), if we fix a point on that curve, y = F(x), then  the perpendicular line at that point is Y - y = (-1/dF(x)) * (X - x) . This is known as the slope intercept formula (google it).